# CSS not affecting bootstrap navbar background color

Tags: html, css, web, flask

I'm trying to set a new color for a bootstrap navbar component but having trouble. Does it have to do with failure to override bootstrap or css link placement? I've tried omitting the bootstrap bg-light setting and defining the navbar background color in main.css as well. What am I missing? Here is the HTML of interest:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}


{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock title %}

{% block html_attribs %}lang='en'{% endblock html_attribs %}

{% block head %}
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    {% block meta %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    {% endblock meta %}

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css' )}}">

    <title>Welcome</title>

    {% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Login</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    {% endblock navbar %}
  </head>
{% endblock head %}

{% block body %}
<body>
    <h1></h1>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
{% endblock body %}

{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

And here is the "main.css" file:

```
body {
    background: #F9DCC4;
    color: #333333;
  }

  .navbar-expand-lg {
    background-color: rgb(150, 144, 143);
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try .navbar-expand-lg {
    background-color: rgb(150, 144, 143) !important;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS rule is most probably being overridden by Bootstrap. Try use the `!important` property, like bellow, or change the order you import your stylesheets.

```
.navbar-expand-lg {
    background-color: rgb(150, 144, 143) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the bg-light class from the navbar and in css you can write -->

```
nav {
    background-color: rgb(150, 144, 143);
   {
```